# Django: websockets connection issues

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels

I am having issues making websockets connection in my django application.
here is the error message

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8000/chat/' failed:
```

**my javascript file**

```
let loc = window.location
let wsStart = 'ws://'

if(loc.protocol === 'https:') {
    wsStart = 'wss://'
}

let endpoint = wsStart + window.location.host + loc.pathname;

var socket = new WebSocket(endpoint)

socket.onopen = async function(e){
     console.log('open', e)
}
socket.onmessage = async function(e){
     console.log('message', e)
}
```

**routing.py**

```
websocket_urlpatterns = [
   path('ws/chat/', consumers.ChatConsumer.as_asgi()),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve it by changing my asgi.py file from

```
"""
ASGI config for social_book project.

It exposes the ASGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/deployment/asgi/
"""

import os
import chatapp.routing
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'social_book.settings')


application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'http': get_asgi_application(),
    'websocket': AuthMiddlewareStack({
        URLRouter(
            chatapp.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    })
})
```

**To**

```
"""
ASGI config for social_book project.

It exposes the ASGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/deployment/asgi/
"""

import os
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack

from chatapp.routing import websocket_urlpatterns

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'social_book.settings')

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'http': get_asgi_application(),
    'websocket': AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    )
})
```

**messages.js**

```
const loc = window.location;
const wsStart = loc.protocol === 'https:' ? 'wss://' : 'ws://';
const endpoint = wsStart + loc.host + '/ws/chat/';

const socket = new WebSocket(endpoint);

socket.onopen = function (event) {
    console.log('WebSocket connection opened:', event);
};

socket.onmessage = function (event) {
    console.log('WebSocket message received:', event);
    // Handle incoming messages as needed
};

socket.onerror = function (event) {
    console.error('WebSocket error:', event);
};

socket.onclose = function (event) {
    console.log('WebSocket connection closed:', event);
};
```